# Webbased Chart Component Prefrably Free for PHP!

Tags: php, flash, charts, fusioncharts

I am looking for a web based chart component, that would allow me to render Rank charts when less value is good. I am aware of fusion charts but does it allow Rank Charting?.. ummm thats a question.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two i have used are,

http://www.maani.us/xml_charts/

And

http://code.google.com/apis/charttools/index.html

I have found then both to be quite reliable. I use the google one for an application monitoring tool where lower numbers are better, so this should fit your requirements.

Comment: Does these components allow Rank Charts (if you have confusion about charts then Rank charts are Line chart but Y axis reversed) we can do that by negating the values but that goes to negative axis does not look quite good!

Comment: this is an example of Rank Chart

http://traffic.alexa.com/graph?&w=400&h=220&o=f&c=1&y=t&b=ffffff&n=666666&r=3m&u=bing.com&

Comment: Yes, http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/gallery/linechart.html. Specifically look at the vAxis.direction, which allows you to do what you want

Answer (score 0):

There's an awesome web based charting application used by karma crm, cannot recall r
The name exactly now. You can feed data in XML and json format to render the charts.